# Any shorter way of implementing nested loops in c++?

Tags: c++, loops

For example, if we want a program to do the following:

```
    int sum=0;
    for(int a=0; a<10; ++a)
    for(int b=0; b<10; ++b)
    for(int c=0; c<10; ++c)
    for(int d=0; d<1-; ++d)
    sum+=max(max(a,b),max(c,d));
```

Here,it's fine as for now because there are only 3 nested loops. My question is if we had for example 20 nested loops to deal with , Is there a way we can cut short the efforts?

Comment: It depends on the problem. Your loops work (In the question) can be done at compile-time too.

Comment: The short form of this fragment is `int sum = 74667;`

Comment: Most likely when you want to nest random amounts of loops in programming, you actually want to use algorithms and you are now trying to brute force them. Figure out what you want to do, find the algorithm that matches and use that, not loop-ception. To do this, figure out the inputs (dynamic, general, not static values) and the outputs and find the way to get there for any set of valid inputs.

Comment: Without a description of what the loops are achieving, it's impossible in general. With a description of what they are achieving- and any constraints on acceptable values of the indices, it *may* be possible. That is the basis of algorithm design. More effective algorithms can do things with less code and/or more efficiently by (for example) avoiding repeated calculations. In worst case, even the "best" algorithm cannot improve anything. In your particular case (assuming `1-` is  a typo of `10`)  it is trivial to eliminate the innermost loop and reduce the range over which other loops iterate.

Comment: One thing you could do is write an "Odometer" class that contains a vector of integers.  Give it an `increment()` method that you call to increment the odometer-readout by one (with appropriate rollover/carry logic when a given digit goes past 9), and call that method in a single for-loop (interleaved with your `sum += [...]` code) unit the odometer rolls back to its initial/all-zeroes state.  One advantage of doing it that way (in addition to the reduced lines of calling code) is that you can specify the number of "dials" in the odometer dynamically at run-time.

Comment: *My question is if we had for example 20 nested loops to deal with* -- You would only have 20 nested loops to deal with because that's the "solution" you came up with for the problem.  If we know what the actual problem is you're trying to solve, there are better ways than having 20 nested loops.  Also, your question is close, to, if not an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: You can opften replace a nested loop with a single loop: `int sum = 0; for(int a=0; a<10000; ++a) sum+=max((max((a/1000)%10,(a/100)%10),max((a/10)%10,a%10))` but a nested loop is usually more readable.

Comment: Compiler optimizations should now take care of most [Loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) for you (there are specific options to influence the behavior). If you are looking to optimize manually from an educational standpoint, that is one traditional approach.

Comment: Aside: `sum += std::max({a, b, c, d})`

Answer (score 1):

you can use a recursion and an array for loop vars, something like the following. I just suggest not to use `10` in the loop or you will wait for your results forever :-)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int loopVar[20] = {0};

int summarize(int i){
  if (i == 20)
    return 0;
  int sum = 0;
  for(loopVar[i] = 0; loopVar[i] < 2; loopVar[i]++)
      sum += summarize(i+1);
  
  return sum + max(loopVar[3], loopVar[5]);
}

int main() {
  cout << summarize(0) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why declaring the `loopVar[20]` globally?

Comment: This is just a demonstration of a possible solution. The variable can be declared locally, e.g, in *main* and passed as an argument to the 'summarize' function.  It just has to be visible across all recursive calls because it is supposed to be modified and referenced to calculate sum as in the OPs example.

Comment: I guess you can use `static` to keep the values saved even after function end (till end of the program).

Comment: sure, you can do it as well.

Comment: That's because it sounds better to declare the variable as static rather than declaring the variable globally.

Answer (score 0):

A SuperInteger class made of many sub indexes, and an Index classn using the a begin and end of SuperInteger Class type, maybe used to write a main with a unique for loop (SuperIntegers with 1 sub index more should be used now to be sure the last element exists)

This mathematic result is also used (trivial demonstration) :

```
max (max (a, b), (max (c,d)) == max (a, b, c, d)
```

Using this Index and Super Integer, sum calculated is 74667 like with nested loops, (a final max_subindex () has to be performed after the loop):

```
int main (int argc, char * argv []) {
  //m = max (max (i, j), max (k, l) <=> m = max (i, j, k, l)
  SuperInteger beg (5, 0, 0, 0, 0), end (5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1);
  Index index (beg, end);
  int sum (0);
  for (; !index.end (); ++index) {
    sum += index.max_subindex ();
  }
  sum += index.max_subindex ();
  std::cout << "sum == " << sum << std::endl;
  //sum == 74667
}
```

And the SuperInteger class :

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <iostream>
#define MAXSUBINDEX 100

class SuperInteger {
  friend class Index;
public :
  SuperInteger (int siz, ...) : size_ (siz) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, siz);
    int* pval ((int*) val_);
    for(int i = 1; i <= siz; i++, ++pval) {
        *pval = va_arg (ap, int);
    }
    va_end(ap);    
  }

  ~SuperInteger () {}
  SuperInteger (const SuperInteger& pn) : size_ (pn.size_) {
    size_ = pn.size_;
    int* p ((int*)val_);
    const int* q ((const int*) pn.val_);
    for (int i (0); i != size_; ++i, ++p, ++q) *p = *q;
  }

  SuperInteger& operator = (const SuperInteger& pn) {
    size_ = pn.size_;
    int* p ((int*)val_);
    const int* q ((const int*) pn.val_);
    for (int i (0); i != size_; ++i, ++p, ++q) *p = *q;
    return *this;
  }

  bool operator == (const SuperInteger& pn) const {
    if (size_ != pn.size_) return false;
    const int* p ((const int*)val_);
    const int* q ((const int*)pn.val_);
    for (int i (0); i != size_; ++i, ++p, ++q) if (*p != *q) return false;
    return true;
  }

  bool operator != (const SuperInteger& pn) const {
    return !operator == (pn);
  }
#ifdef _DEBUG 
  void write (std::ostream& os) const {
    const int* p ((const int*)val_);
    for (int i (0); i != size_; ++i, ++p) {os << *p << " ";}
  }
#endif

  int operator [] (const int& i) const {
    return val_ [i];
  }
  int& operator [] (const int& i) {
    return val_ [i];
  }

  int max_subindex () const {
    int m (0);
    const int* p ((const int*) val_);
    for (int i (0); i != size_; ++i, ++p)if (*p>m) m = *p;
    return m;
  }

//private :
  int size_;
  int val_ [MAXSUBINDEX];
};
```

and finally, the Index class, with a preincrementation method

```
class Index {
public :
  Index (SuperInteger beg, SuperInteger end) : beg_ (beg), val_ (beg), end_ (end) {}
  Index (const Index& i) : beg_ (i.beg_), val_ (i.val_), end_ (i.end_) {}
  Index& operator = (const Index& i) {
    beg_ = i.beg_;
    val_ = i.val_;
    end_ = i.end_;
    return *this;
  }
  bool operator == (const Index& i) const {
    return (val_ == i.val_?true:false);
  }
  bool operator != (const Index& i) const {
    return !operator == (i);
  }

  void operator ++ () {
    bool carry (true);
    int i (0); //, j (i);
    while (carry) {
      if (val_ [i] +1 < end_ [i]) {
        ++val_ [i];
        carry = false;
      }
      else {
        val_ [i] = beg_ [i];
        ++i;
      }
    }
  }
  bool end () const {
    for ( int i (0); i != val_.size_; ++i) {
      if (val_ [i] +1 != end_ [i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  int max_subindex () const {
    return val_.max_subindex ();
  }
#ifdef _DEBUG
  void write (std::ostream& os) {
    val_.write (os);
  }
#endif
  SuperInteger beg_;
  SuperInteger val_;
  SuperInteger end_;
};
```